# addChild in scheduled method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a beginner with `Cocos2d` and I encounter a issue which seems that I can't solve by my own. My problem is that if I add a `CCSprite` in a scheduled method, the background of the added image will be opaque (black), even if the origin is a transparent PNG.  But the code explains better what I'm trying to do, so

```
- (void) openShutters 
{
  NSInteger randomTime = (arc4random() % 3) + 2;
  [self schedule:@selector(openShutter) interval:0 repeat:1 delay:randomTime];
}

- (void) openShutter 
{
  NSInteger randomShutter = (arc4random() % [shutters count]);

  CCSprite *soldier = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"soldier.png"];
  soldier.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1);
  soldier.position = ccp(0, winSize.height);
  [self addChild:soldier];

  [self unschedule:@selector(openShutter)];
  [self openShutters];
}
```

The weird issue here is that if I move `CCSprite *soldier = [CCSprite ...` in `openShutters` method, the sprite will appear with a transparent background, as desired. It's this a bug in `cocos-2d`, a bug in my code or it's not safe to add new childs from scheduled methods?

Answer (score 2):

In openShutters method you are assigning interval=0 this statement creating a problem after setting interval value greater than zero working fine

Comment: Setting interval to a higher value still cause the issue to appear.

Comment: comment this statement //[self openShutters]; in openShutter method

Comment: would you like to explain your problem in details at my end it display  an image after 1 second.

Comment: it also display the image for me, too, the issue is that the image doesn't have its background transparent (see http://i.imgur.com/Xfkcs.png , the soldier's background is black)

Comment: i think two situation are their first one please check this                                      pixelFormat: kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 in app controller and second is may be soldier background not transparent and other may be another case you clear layer background color

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21458/discussion-between-mohd-kalimullah-sheikh-and-ov1d1u)